# Get two acf fields comma separated

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I want to show two acf fields comma separated in single line if both are available, otherwise show one field which is available without comma.

I got the code, but not sure where to put <?php code to make it work.

```
if (get_field('birthDate') {
  $values[] = get_field('birthDate');
}
if (get_field('birthPlace') {
  $values[] = get_field('birthPlace');
}
if (!empty($values)) {
  echo implode(', ', $values);
}
```

Comment: Depends on where you want to show it - and if you are using a pagebuilder etc. - you could make a shortcode out of it, and display it anywhere you want

Comment: But the code is not working.

Comment: Did you initiate the array? `$values = array()` before this code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually I want to display Two ACF field's output in a row separated with comma. If both have values then show both with a comma, and if only one has value then show only one without comma. I also want to hide label if no field has value... Output for example: Born: 1 March 1988, India

Comment: I have two different fields: birthDate and birthPlace... I want to show both of them comma separated, but I dont have full code, can you please help me, I am not sure where to put endif and php tags.